# How can I update the CSRF token when doing login via Ajax?

Tags: laravel

If you do login via Ajax, the current CSRF token that is in the head gets unauthorized, so I need a way to update it.

Taylor Otwell says the CSRF token is already returned as a cookie when doing login via Ajax (source: https://github.com/laravel/ui/pull/79#issuecomment-601719203), but it is not the case (see image below):

[image]

The reason I need to update the CSRF token is because in Apollo Client I have the following configuration:

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: '/graphql',
  headers: {
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content
  }
});
```

Am I missing something? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: is your backend server same domain?

Comment: yes, it is the same domain.